# url.openStream() and httpClient.execute() does not work for some webpages

Tags: java, http, web-scraping, httpclient

I have a block of codes to read URL page content, This code is working good for many pages but does not work for some pages like the link below:

https://www.deutschepost.com/en/business-customers.html/robots.txt

my code is something like this:

```
     String url = https://www.deutschepost.com/en/business-customers.html/robots.txt
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
      //requesting the data using execute();
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    
    //below is for openStream();
      InputStream robotTxtStream = new URL(url).openStream();
```

I am not getting any response not even exception from both "openStream();" or"execute()".
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by not getting any response? The ClosableHttpResponse is `null`? If not then what does `response.getStatusLine()` give you? Also the URL you gave as an example is very strange and even if I curl it, it says `404- Not Found`

Comment: after excuting this line httpClient.execute(request); we will able to get response.getStatusLine(). But console is struck at "httpClient.execute(request)" line only.
I waited for long time.

Comment: It seems that it is also not possible to read any content from that website using URL and Scanner.

Comment: acha.
Is there any other way to solve this problem?@WojciechDomalewski@Tarmo

Comment: I tried it myself also and also got the halting result. I tried debugging to see why, but got nowhere. Anyway, one non-perfect solution is to set timeouts for your HTTP client and just assume it's not reachable if it times out.

Comment: It may have something to do with setting user-agent. I cannot open this page with many other old browsers.